# When does Slot evaluate?

Tags: scoping, sequence

I looked up the related answers, it must have to do with the scope.
Toy example similar to mine in structure:

```
foo[i_] := Array [If[Slot[1] == Slot[i + 1], 0, 1] &, ConstantArray[2, 3]];
```

Fail: in bar[1], Slot[1+1] does not compute. I hotfixed it by using

```
List[##][[i+1]]
```

instead of the 2nd Slot and it works as intended. Of course I can apply generous Where, With etc. statements instead like suggested in the other answers, but I'm just curious: When does Slot goes on Hold? Do other constructs than Slot have the same problem?

Comment: You can use `With` to make sure `i+1` gets evaluated before entering `Slot`: `foo[i_] := With[{j = i + 1},  Array[If[Slot[1] == Slot[j], 0, 1] &, ConstantArray[2,3]] ];`

Comment: Ah, I missed your remark about `With`. Still, for the benefit of readers who don't know how to use `With`.

Answer (score 6):

I'm guessing that this has more to do with `Function` than with `Slot`. If you look at the attributes of `Function` and `Slot`, you'll notice that `Function` is `HoldAll` while `Slot` is `NHoldAll`.

```
Attributes[Function]
Attributes[Slot]

Out[23]= {HoldAll, Protected}

Out[24]= {NHoldAll, Protected}
```

Since this behaviour doesn't have anything to do with `N`, `NHoldAll` isn't really relevant. `Slot` by itself can never distinguish between `2` and `1+1` since the sum would always evaluated before `Slot` sees it.

However, `Function` is `HoldAll` and my guess is that it scans the body of the function (without evaluating it) for patterns of the form `Slot[_Integer]` (or other allowed forms like `Slot[_String]` for Associations) and inserts the function arguments appropriately. Since `Slot[1+1]` does not match `Slot[_Integer]`, `Function` cannot replace that slot with an argument and complains.

So my mental model of `Function` is:

1. Scan body for occurrences of `Slot`. Nothing gets evaluated in this stage
2. Replace `Slot`s with arguments of the function
3. Evaluate body after the replacements

Comment: I think evaluating `Slot[0+1]` and `Slot[0+1]&`corroborates your point